# Why are the engineers completely different between movies?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus, alien-covenant

There are dramatic differences in technological aesthetics and anatomy between the engineers across *Alien*, *Prometheus* and *Covenant*. The differences are extreme enough that they do not look like members of the same species.

Among other things (see the attached image for a side-by-side comparison of anatomy), the engineer in *Alien* is at least twice as large as those in the prequels, does not have legs or any room for legs that are not broken, and is fused with or growing out of the pilot's seat.

[image]

The technology in *Alien* is biomechanical in nature, resembling a weird cross between industrial machinery and bones and mummified bodies. The technology in *Prometheus* and *Covenant* is clearly artificially constructed, but it seems to be aping the aesthetic of *Alien*. The design of the juggernaut/derelict cockpit is different, as the one in *Alien* does not seem intended for walking around, since the floor is full of holes and there are no stairs; whereas the one in *Prometheus* has a flat surface and a convenient staircase.

In *Covenant*, the engineers bear little physical resemblance to the one from *Prometheus*. They appear to be a different species, but they use the same technology.

I am aware that in the prequels the engineers are revealed to be humans wearing suits. This is supposed to be a retroactive change applied to the pilot from *Alien*. That does not explain the obvious disparities in anatomy and technology. I know that these inconsistencies are a result of sloppy production, but I will assume that these differences exist within the fictional universe rather than continuity errors.

This is what the original pilot seat of the derelict ship in *Alien* looked like:

[image]

Based on the shape of the suit and the general Giger aesthetic, the pilot in *Alien* should look something like this:

[image]

The engineers in *Prometheus* look like this:

[image]

The engineers in *Covenant* look like this:

[image]

Comment: While I think this is a decent question, and the answer may just come down to "different filmmakers, different tech, different look", the side by side here is doing more to convince me there's no practical difference at all.

Comment: Because terrible writing.

Comment: ...have you actually seen Prometheus? There's a particular fact revealed in that film which pretty much negates your complaint about Prometheus & Covenant, and also is likely the reason for the changes in body proportions.

Comment: @recognizer Could you point out which fact you are talking about? Maybe with spoiler warning. I watched both movies but can't remember

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Okay, with the edit to the question, it now covers the point I was alluding to. The change in design is because, in Prometheus, the "Space Jockey" was revealed to be a human-like humanoid wearing an elaborate space suit. The Engineers in Covenant are the same as Prometheus, only no longer wearing space suits. If the asker knows all this already, I have no idea what this question is about...

Comment: @recognizer: The jockey clearly is not human because the proportions are all wrong. That "suit" is fused to the wearer. The makeup effects are clearly different between movies. They are not the same. Why are they not the same?

Comment: @Anonymous It seems self-evident to me that the appearance of the Space Jockey design was altered for Prometheus so that a humanoid Engineer could feasibly fit inside it as a suit.

Comment: @recognizer: I am assuming that the differences exist in-universe rather than being sloppy retcons. I thought I said so in the body of the question.

Comment: Let's consider; The Engineers are masters of manipulating biology, and that includes *their own bodies*. Would it be unreasonable to expect that they might have different forms developed for different environments? Or even be able to change their shape to resemble any lifeforms they are contacting ( Instead of encounter suits)?

Answer (score 1):

So if you compared an Australian Aboriginal to an Anglo-Saxon from western Europe, would you say they aren't the same species?

There can quite easily be variation within a species, especially if they are advanced enough to breed or modify themselves as they see fit.

Have a look at the first scene in *Prometheus* where the engineer sacrifices himself with goo, and compare him to the elders standing behind him. That engineer was probably bred to be the perfect specimen, so that the DNA and genes that were left there would have the best effect on populating the planet.

Comment: Apparent racial differences among a specific alien species isn't at all a common trend in sci fi movies. As such, it should not be considered obvious, and would need more backing.

Answer (score 0):

The engineers society (for lack of a better term) had many different variations dependent upon any given function. The 'differences' noted result from this - different buttons, same machine.

I find the varied striations of the engineers society in the film(s) themselves.
A certain class to begin the life cycle on any given world, as shown in deleted (but view-able) scenes where taking the parasite was akin to a deeply religious rite.

The innate command arrogance of the one builder we saw in the film, why did only he have access to a viable life support system of the entire crew. Our 'standard' alien resulted from this commander.

The scene in which all of the parasites are released onto the engineers home world, where the crowds resemble a bustling open air market and multiple variations are seen amid the crowds.

Bear in mind also that no one on the engineers home world saw anything unusual in the ships' return (prior to the parasite dump). In the films time line that ship, indeed that entire base in which the majority of the film takes place, had been defunct for several millennia (based upon the 'clues' from earth that brought the humans there.

Given this, it is only logical that the engineers had multiple ships and crews constantly arriving & departing from all over, given that the specific ship that the parasite was dumped from hadn't been 'home' in millennia, yet no alarm was raised at its arrival, rather the crowd rejoiced to see it.

Everything points to a widespread and diverse, far flung society. This diversity almost 'demands' that the engineers were not wholly genocide with the loss of their home world.

Bear in mind too that the original film Alien had an 'undecipherable' signal emanating from the crashed ship, the Engineer deliberately crashing his infected ship on a non viable world and setting a beacon to warn off his people. I know in the latter part of Alien they suddenly decided the signal was a warning to stay away.

Everything thus far in the film franchise, books & games, all point to a diverse culture of engineers.

Comment: Could you [edit] to provide evidence for why you think this is the case?

Comment: I actually forgot about the warning signal. The audio of it was clearly inhuman (as in a human vocal apparatus could not produce it), yet in Prometheus the engineer speaks Indo-European.

Comment: @Anonymous there is no evidence that the warning signal from Alien was set by the pilot or crew of the ship in Alien - it could have been another species entirely, who avoided the fate of the Nostromo...